# Finding the frequency of repetation of Material pairs in Sales order and order them by Frequency in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

my data looks like shown below.I want to create material pairs Sales Order Wise which is being ordered frequently in SQL Server I used the below code but I see duplicates in the output.

```
SALES_ORDER-    ITEM_NO-    MATERIAL_NUMBER<br>
160608048   10  EU-SAC-00820<br>
160608047   10  EU-174000-000200<br>
160608047   20  EU-174000-000180<br>
160608047   30  EU-174000-000220<br>
160608042   10  EU-A-6000-08LF<br>
160608040   10  EU-A-6000-08LF<br>
160608038   10  EU-4843<br>
160608038   20  EU-4844<br>
160608038   30  EU-4842<br>
```

```
SELECT  A1.[Document],A1.[FINAL Material],A2.[Document],A2.[FINAL Material] FROM [dbo].[Sheet1$] A1,[dbo].[Sheet1$] A2 WHERE A1.[Document]= A2.[Document] AND A1.[FINAL Material] != A2.[FINAL Material]
```